# get dyanmic key matching value using angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs

i have a n input json as like

```
     var err=  {"errors": 
                       {"username": ["Invalid login ID"],
                         "password": ["Invalid password"]
                }
               };
```

I have to fetch the values of username and password using  angular.forEach. Any code snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(err['username'], function (username) {
    // here you will get all data which are part of username
    console.log(username); // You will see result as "Invalid login ID"
});

angular.forEach(err['password'], function (password) {
    // here you will get all data which are part of username
    console.log(password); // You will see result as "Invalid password"
});
```